# sonar module already part of project

Tags: sonarqube

I'm really stuck on this:

1) existing project I has module A

2) create new project and move module A into new project II

Sonar tells me module A is already part of project I.

I've tried all manner of exclusion patterns etc and got nowhere.

the (maven) module is at 'feature-A' level.

${project.baseDir}/my-features/feature-A/benefit-1

Hints or suggestions please!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SonarQube: How to analyze project that used to be submodule of another project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35433891/sonarqube-how-to-analyze-project-that-used-to-be-submodule-of-another-project) (I know it is more recent but it seemed better to me)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967387/sonarqube-transfer-module-to-another-project

Answer (score 4):

I found 2 solutions for this problem:

1. Rename the key of the submodule in projekt I (Project configuration > Update key)
2. Delete project I.

Comment: This solution works for me. Keys were creating conflicts. Thanks.

Comment: Option 2. Delete Project worked for me. But on second mvn sonar:sonar execution, the generation of the report was successful, however, certain metrics like vulnerabilities and bugs were not shown. So, in addition, $SONARQUBE_HOME/data/es will have to be deleted/renamed(better option), to clear cache and sonar restarted and show the vulnerabilities, bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly more complex scenario since I got a branch of the project with a single maven build, and a second branch where the main artifact become a submodule (preserving it original groupId/artifactId) while the parent changed its name.

The solution was to keep the original key for the legacy project and instead adding a property only in the submodule to change sonar project key.

```
<sonar.projectKey>org.mycompany:myprojectModule</sonar.projectKey>
```

this let the old project go on with his history on the already existing project on sonar, while the new one get it's own new Key as a submodule of the parent.

Moreover since I declare project name as

```
<name>projectName${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}:${project.packaging}</name>
```

aslo the name of the project displayed in sonar interface is the correct one (e.g. the one WITHOUT the new key) in both analysis

In this way I can have both project going on with sonar analysis independently without any history loss