# SonarQube: How to analyze project that used to be submodule of another project?

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I have a project with an aggregator POM and several submodules:

```
com.example:root
  |- com.example:module-a
  |- com.example:module-b
  |- com.example:module-c
```

It was decided that `module-b` needs to be a separate project, so the directory `module-b` was split off into a separate git repository.

Now we have 2 projects:

```
com.example:root
  |- com.example:module-a
  |- com.example:module-c

com.example:module-b
```

`com.example:root` was analyzed for a long time with SonarQube. I use the maven goal `sonar:sonar`.

Now when I analyze `com.example:module-b` with SonarQube, I get this error:

```
2016.02.16 13:03:24 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Failed to execute task AVLqLZdJf9ZlZw0WwFfK
org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: Validation of project failed:
  o The project "com.example:project-b" is already defined in SonarQube but as a module of project "com.example:root". If you really want to stop directly analysing project "com.example:root", please first delete it from SonarQube and then relaunch the analysis of project "com.example:project-b".
2016.02.16 13:03:24 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Executed task | project=com.example:project-b | id=AVLqLZdJf9ZlZw0WwFfK | time=302ms
```

The thing is, yes, in the past `com.example:project-b` was indeed a module of `com.example:root`, but it isn't any more now. I also don't want to stop analyzing `com.example:root` and I don't want to delete it and loose all history and all other modules.

How do I solve this?

Comment: is module-b still pointing to root as its parent? or is it a completely de-coupled project?

Comment: Yes, `module-b` still points to `root`. Should that matter? SonarQube only looks at `<groupId>:<artifactId>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have SonarQube 5.1.2.  This is how I would try to fix this issue with our version.  If this exact procedure doesn't work, maybe it will give you ideas for solving the problem and then we'll refine the answer.

- Log into SonarQube
- View the multi-module project
- In the project menu, click Settings --> Update Key
- Find `module-b` in the list of keys, and provide an alternative name - maybe `module-b-old`
- Run multi-module analysis to see if that still works
- Run `module-b` analysis to see if that works now.

There is also a Reset link; not sure what that does.

Comment: Sonarqube 5.3 here. The menu is named slightly different, but I found it. Renamed the module to -old, ran an analysis, and there was much rejoicing.

Comment: The reset link recovers the original name of the module.