# Sonar complains that a project is already defined in SonarQube but not as a module of project

Tags: mysql, maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.6

After upgrading from SonarQube 5.1.2 to SonarQube 5.6, we started facing the below issue.

ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Failed to execute task AVX_lJ9fzEKnCGDDOpXH
org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: Validation of project failed:
The project 'X' is already defined in SonarQube but not as a module of project "Y". If you really want to stop directly analysing project "X", please first delete it from SonarQube and then relaunch the analysis of project "Y".

We haven't done any changes or refactored our code apart from upgrading. please let us know how to fix the issue.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35444713/944849) may point you in the correct direction. The location in the UI is likely a little different for 5.6.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but the answer was not the one I was expecting for, as I said in the above mail , code wise I haven't changed anything (It is the same old module) and on SonarQube 5.1.2 sonar analysis was happening without any issues, only after upgrading to SonarQube 5.6 I'm facing this issue. Please let me know if you have any fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharieff,

I had faced a similar situation in my project. For me it was the sonar.skippedModules property which was still mentioned in my pom.xml. Since this property is no more supported since SonarQube 5.5, SonarQube may have problems analyzing the modules as they already would have entries in the database.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Anantha

Comment: Yes Anantha, It was the case and to exclude the modules in pom.xml I've used <sonar.skip>true</sonar.skip> and it worked fine. Thanks a lot.