# sonarqube transfer module to another project

Tags: sonarqube

I have the following situation:

```
project A
  - sub module A
  - sub module B
```

I want to move the sub module B to another project:

```
project B
  - sub module B
```

But now sonarQube comes up with the following error:

```
Module "submoduleB" is already part of project "projectA"
```

I could rename key in project A so that it can be used again in project B but then I probably lose the history. Thus, how can I transfer the module's history to another project?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35433891/sonarqube-how-to-analyze-project-that-used-to-be-submodule-of-another-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't transfer the history.

You *could* recreate it using `sonar.projectDate` ([docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters#AnalysisParameters-ProjectConfiguration.1)), but you'll have to do that for the project as a whole; you can't retroactively insert new data into old analyses.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. That's a pity. Project A has years of analysis history. So what would be your suggestion to follow. Rename the sub module in project A so it can be reused in project B?

Comment: You need to re-key it. Name doesn't really matter (except as a factor in human confusion).

Comment: Ah.. wrong wording. I meant, rename the key of the submodule (Administration -> Update Key). Right?

Comment: Yup. (Stupid minimum comment length!)